# nodejs - parsing and storing return of a function into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, io

How would I go about parsing the output returned from a function call, line by line, into an array where one line from output would be one array element?

I can naively do it via storing to a file and then reading the file back-in, but this seems to be unnecessary overhead and not a very elegant and tidy solution.

Comment: Can you show us what the nature of the output is? What code do you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to split the data on carriage return. e.g.

```
var myArray = data.split('\n');
```

converts a file

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
```

to an array:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ',
'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna ',
'aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation']
```

So, to parse the data on the fly you could do:

```
var myProcessedArray =
     myFunction()    // produces some multi-line data
         .split('\n') // now we have array of strings
         .map(function(line) {
             // process lines
             line = line.replace('ipsum', ''); // remove the word 'ipsum'
             return line;
         })
```